# Enhance Python performance pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, rdbms

I have two pandas dataframes looking like this

| ID | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "firstname.lastname@provider.com" | "firstname lastname" |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 5150 | "firstname.lastname@provider.com" | "firstname lastname" |

with roughly 5150 rows. The data is not cleaned in the sense that it may happen that the `name` column contains names with typos, additional spaces, written in camelcase. Also it may be that the name is an empty string.

The second dataframe contains information like this

| Id | Email | Name | To | To_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "firstname.lastname@provider.com" | "firstname lastname" | "firstname.lastname@provider.com" | "firstname lastname" |
| ... | ... | ... |  |  |
| 8500 | "firstname.lastname@provider.com" | "firstname lastname" | "firstname.lastname@provider.com" | "firstname lastname" |

with roughly 8500 rows. Here, the `name` columns have the same issue as the first dataframe.

I now want to create a new dataframe out of the previous two dataframes in the sense of relational databases, i.e. in the form

| ID | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |

where the `ID` column refers to the `ID` column of the second dataframe and the values in the `From` and `To` column refer to the first dataframe where we map names onto integers.

The code below runs but takes roughly one minute. Do you guys have ideas how I could speed it up?

```
Id_new = []
From_new = []
To_new = []

for i in range(0,len(second_df['Id'])):

    Id_new.append(second_df['Id'].iloc[i])
    email = second_df['Email'].iloc[i]
    name = second_df['Name'].iloc[i]
    testdf = first_Df.where(first_Df['Email'] == email).dropna()
    value = int(testdf.loc[testdf['Name'] == name].iloc[0].at["ID"])
    From_new.append(value)

    emailto = second_df['To'].iloc[i]
    nameto = second_df['To_Name'].iloc[i]
    testdf = first_Df.where(first_Df['Email'] == emailto).dropna()
    valueto = int(testdf.loc[testdf['Name'] == nameto].iloc[0].at["ID"])
    To_new.append(valueto)
        
    return output_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Id_new, From_new, To_new)),
                             columns = ['ID', 'From', 'To'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to avoid running for loops when dealing with pandas DataFrames, most of the times there is a better way of doing it. In this case you probably want to use `merge` [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

You can merge first on `email` and `name` and then on `to` and `to_name`, something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{"ID": ["1", "2", "3"], "email": ["a", "b", "c"], "name": ["x", "y", "z"]}
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "Id": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    "email": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "name": ["x", "y", "z", "k"],
    "to": ["m", "a", "b", "p"],
    "to_name": ["r", "x", "y", "u"],
}
)

new_df = (
df2.merge(df1[["ID", "email", "name"]], on=["email", "name"], how="left")
.rename(columns={"ID": "From"})
.merge(df1, right_on=["email", "name"], left_on=["to", "to_name"], how="left")
.rename(columns={"ID": "To"})[["Id", "From", "To"]]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for some SQL-like approach

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to iterate the first list extracting the name and id into a dict. Then, iterate the second list also extracting the name and id and enriching the previous dict creating the resulting table.

```
result = {}
for index, row in first_df.iterrows():
   result[row["Name"]] = {"From": row["Id"]}

for index, row in second_df.iterrows():
   if row["Name"] in result:
      result[row["Name"]]["To"] = row["Id"]
   else:
      result[row["Name"]] = {"To": row["Id"]}
```

This way, you only iterate once on each dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([ { "ID": 1, "email": "firstname1.lastname@provider.com", "name": "firstname lastname" }, { "ID": 2, "email": "firstname2.lastname@provider.com", "name": "firstname lastname" } ])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ { "Id": 1, "Email": "firstname2.lastname@provider.com", "Name": "firstname lastname", "To": "firstname1.lastname@provider.com", "To_Name": "firstname lastname" }, { "Id": 2, "Email": "firstname1.lastname@provider.com", "Name": "firstname lastname", "To": "firstname2.lastname@provider.com", "To_Name": "firstname lastname" } ])

df2[['Email', 'To']] = df2[['Email', 'To']].replace(df1.set_index('email')['ID'])
final_df = df2[['Id', 'Email', 'To']]
```

Output:

|  | Id | Email | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |